# Printing node on multiple pages

Tags: java, printing, javafx, javafx-8

I have a table view that can't fit on one page but when I print it only one page gets printed. What should I do so that the rest of the table is printed on other pages?

Sample code below that fills a table view with 50 rows and prints it (I use foxit as a pdf printer, amend as required). The output pdf only contains one page that ends around row 30 although the TableView shows more than 45 rows.

```
public class FXPrint extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(FXPrint.class); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TableView<String> table = new TableView<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            TableColumn<String, String> tc = new TableColumn<>("" + i);
            int index = i;
            tc.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
                String s = param.getValue();
                if (s.length() <= index) return new SimpleStringProperty();
                else return new SimpleStringProperty(s.substring(index, index + 1));
            });
            table.getColumns().add(tc);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) table.getItems().add(i + "sdfghjklrthyjkcasdghasfdsfgdfgsdfggfdg");

        Button print =  new Button("print");
        print.setOnAction(e -> print(table));

        VBox box = new VBox(10, table, print);
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(box));
        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(1200);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void print(final TableView<?> table) {
        Printer printer = Printer.getAllPrinters().stream().filter(p -> p.getName().contains("Foxit")).findAny().get();
        PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
        if (job != null) {
            job.getJobSettings().setPageLayout(pageLayout);
            if (job.printPage(table)) {
                job.endJob();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should split your TableView on multiple Nodes according to height of printable area and height of your rows. Then call job.PrintPage for all nodes, and once job.endJob.
Here is my approach for multiple pages printing:

```
public static List<Node> getLineRecordPages(Collection<LineRecord> lineRecords, PageLayout layout) {
        LinkedList<Node> result = new LinkedList<>();
        VBox node = null;
        double totalHeight = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        for (LineRecord record : lineRecords) {
            PrintLineRecordView view = new PrintLineRecordView();
            final PrintLineRecordPresenter presenter = (PrintLineRecordPresenter) view.getPresenter();
            presenter.bind(record);
            final double elementHeight = view.getView().prefHeight(layout.getPrintableWidth());
            if (elementHeight + totalHeight > layout.getPrintableHeight()) {
                node = new VBox();
                node.setMaxWidth(layout.getPrintableWidth());
                result.add(node);
                totalHeight = 0;
            }
            totalHeight+=elementHeight;
            if (node != null) {
                node.getChildren().add(view.getView());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And actualy sending pages to printing job:

```
Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
PageLayout pageLayout = printer.getDefaultPageLayout();
PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob(printer);
final List<Node> pages = Formatter.getLineRecordPages(lineRecords, pageLayout);
final boolean print = printerJob.showPrintDialog(null);
if (print) {
    pages.forEach(printerJob::printPage);
    printerJob.endJob();
}
```

Comment: could you please take a look at my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310677/printing-multiple-nodes-in-javafx?lq=1)

Comment: What is LineRecord,PrintLineRecordView,PrintLineRecordPresenter ? where are declared ?